# Old resource file being served to clients, container running in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, cache

I've encountered a problem with one of our containers and can not understand what is causing the issue.  We have several microservices running in a Kubernetes deployment that also uses istio. All of the infrastructure is running in AWS.

A few days ago we deployed a new image for one of the services.  We use Flux and kustomize to control deployments.  There was a problem with the registry URL, so on the first push, the new container failed to deploy.  The registry URL was corrected and the new container deployed successfully.  However, I did notice there were two StatefulSet objects defined - one for the old image and one for the new.  The old image showed current and desired were 0, so K8s was not trying to use that statefulset, but I deleted it anyways.

Later we found out that some people were viewing icons loaded by the app that were not showing up correctly.  The reason is some people were still being served an old sprite image from the old container, while other people were seeing the new sprite image.

The application owners assured us there is no client-side caching in their app, and I verified by loading the app on a new machine that has never loaded it before and the icons were still broken (new machine somehow referencing old sprite resource) - I also did the standard checks of clearing cache, trying a different browser, and using incognito.  I made sure only a single container was running which was the new version, so as far as I can tell we don't have traffic going to any old container with the old sprite resource.  The issue also "sticks" to people.  The people who see broken icons always see them as broken and vice versa.

This is screaming some kind of caching behavior to me, but I don't know which tool in our stack could be caching a resource from a container on the infrastructure side.  Has anyone ever encountered an issue like this or have any ideas what could be caching a resource file?